# Using 2 Cursors to Find Return Appointments

Tags: sql-server, cursor

In our system we have a situation where hospital patients can come back to the hospital for unscheduled readmissions (this is determined by the ward they are readmitted to). In the data I am looking for unscheduled readmissions that have come back within a certain time with respect to their last appointment.

So I might have:

John Smith Admitted: 20th Sept 2013, discharged 22nd of Sept 2013

Then another record to unscheduled admissions (identified by special ward) below:

John Smith Admitted: 25th Sept 2013, discharged 28th of Sept 2013

So what i need to do is check the data difference between discharged in 1st record and admission date in 2nd record, and if the difference in days is less than or equal to 7 days and the person went to unscheduled admissions ward then I display this data.

I brought in all the data to SQL Server with the idea to create one cursor to step through all records and a nested cursor to step through all records relating to unscheduled admissions only.

The way I am distinguishing data in the nested and main cursor is the ward they were admitted to and their admission ID (unique) not being the same as in the main cursor record but the patient ID being a match.

This means I would not be comparing the same record for an admission but would be looking at the same patient's other admission records and checking if it was within 7 days.

The code I used is below and the main problem I am having is using a datediff function in the cursor.

```
DECLARE C_Admmissions CURSOR FOR
    SELECT PatientID, [admission date], [discharge date], admissionid, [ward code]  
    FROM Admissions

    open C_Admmissions

    FETCH NEXT 
    FROM C_Admmissions into @PatientID, @admissiondate, @dischargedate, @admissionid, @wardcode 

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
    BEGIN

        DECLARE C_unscheduled_Admmissions CURSOR FOR
        SELECT PatientID, [admission date], [discharge date], admissionid, [ward code]  
        FROM Admissions
        WHERE [ward code] = 'unsch_adm'
        AND admissionid != @admissionid
        AND [PatientID] = @PatientID

        open C_unscheduled_Admmissions

        FETCH NEXT FROM C_unscheduled_Admmissions into @PatientID2, @admissiondate2, @dischargedate2, @admissionid2, @wardcode2

        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
            BEGIN

              begin     
               if DATEDIFF(DD, @dischargedate, @admissiondate2)<=7

                begin
                insert into unscheduled_admissions values(@PatientID, @admissiondate, @dischargedate, @admissionid, @wardcode)
                end

                begin
                insert into unscheduled_admissions values(@PatientID2, @admissiondate2, @dischargedate2, @admissionid2, @wardcode2)
                end     
              end   

            FETCH NEXT 
            FROM C_unscheduled_Admmissions into @PatientID2, @admissiondate2, @dischargedate2, @admissionid2, @wardcode2
            END
        CLOSE C_unscheduled_Admmissions
        DEALLOCATE C_unscheduled_Admmissions

    FETCH NEXT 
    FROM C_Admmissions into @CHI, @admissiondate, @dischargedate, @admissionid, @wardcode
    END
    CLOSE C_Admmissions
    DEALLOCATE C_Admmissions
    END

GO
```

I'm inserting the admission and readmission values into a table to see what data I get and instead of getting an admission that then shows a readmission in then next row less than 7 days later (from the previous discharge date) it just shows all admissions and readmissions with less than 7 days between admission and discharge on the same row of data.

The processing isn't on a live system and the total data rows I am working with are about 170,000.

What I am expecting to see seems to be what the code should be giving but it's not and I can't see why. It's probably something obvious in the logic I am missing.

Andrew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't sound like you need even a single cursor. Something like this should produce the data that you need (although maybe not in the format you desire):

```
SELECT *
FROM
   Admissions first
      INNER JOIN
   Admissions readmit
      ON
         first.PatientID = readmit.PatientID AND
         first.AdmissionID < readmit.AdmissionID AND
         DATEDIFF(day,first.[discharge date],readmit.[admission date]) <= 7
WHERE
   readmit.[ward code] = 'unsch_adm'
```

(Not having your data, this is untested).

It's possible that your original code is faulting because you never check that the readmission occurs after the original admission at all. In the above, I've assumed `first.AdmissionID < readmit.AdmissionID` will cover that (instead of your `!=` check) - an alternative would be `first.[discharge date] < readmit.[admission date]` on that line.

```
DATEDIFF(day,<recent date>,<date in the far past>)
```

will produce a negative value - which is less than 7.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I was playing about with queries but could not get it to work. The AdmissionID is alphanumeric so would need to not equal another ID as one of the criteria. I also realised the negative number problem with the datediff and swapped the fields for readmission date and first discharge date and added another condition but still getting wrong results

Comment: The date display from print is like this 'Sep 20 2013 12:00AM' and in a query result set is like this: '2013-09-20 00:00:00.000' - would this screw up the datediff check?

Comment: @Andrew - hopefully, in the database, their being stored as `datetime` values (which don't *have* any formatting). If they're strings then more work may be required.

Comment: I think I do need to use something other than cursor as it takes ages to process.

Comment: @Andrew - the same general query I've shown should work - as I say, without having your data, I'm unable to test it. But the gist is that this is a self-join of a table to itself. The join conditions are (line 1) that they're rows for the same patient, (line 2) that the row aliased `first` comes from an earlier time than the row aliased `readmit`, and (line 3) that the gap between them is less than or equal to 7 days. I'd hope you'd be able to tweak from that to actually match it up with your data.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I did produce a similar query but ended up with an inline view, this appears to have worked for me.